# Commerce cart allowing quantity than In stock

Tags: commerce

I don't know on how to validate the quantity, meaning if user add the quantity more than In stock, it should not allow the user to add more quantity than In stock(quantity available), I think it can be achieved in rules, but Im not sure to do that any pointer would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[commerce stock module](https://www.drupal.org/project/Commerce_stock) check the quantity and prevent add max than stock,also if the stock be 0 it change `add to cart` button to `out of stock`.

Also if you want to implement it by yourself you can do it with rules

Comment: I already installed commerce stock module, but it is not preventing the quantity! any idea ?

Comment: I think this is a bug in commerce stock module

Comment: Sorry its my mistake, I forget to enable the commerce simple stock rules module.